# is it possible to hide :hover element (pure css) when tapping outside again on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, hover

I use double tap (on iPhone) on :hover elements to show extra information, without javascript, just simple css :hover pseudoclass. Now I've the problem that the div, that appears on :hover doesn't disappear anymore, only if I tap on another :hover element. 
Has the :hover-functionality changed in iOS?

```
li.to-be-hovered {
  position:relative;
}
li.to-be-hovered div.hidden {
  display:none;
}
li.to-be-hovered:hover div.hidden {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

And some more like width, top, left, margin, background, z-index and so on...

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="to-be-hovered">
      <div class="hidden">
        lots of extra information with image, span, link elements
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On my iPhone (4S) the div.hidden appears at first tab on div.to-be-hovered, but doesn't disappear anymore when tapping somewhere else outside the element.
Does anybody know this effect? Is it possible to make it disappear again with pure CSS or do I have to use Javascript for all these elements?

Comment: Touchscreens and `:hover` don't play well together. Use `:active` instead. In this case, a pure CSS approach might not be possible.

Comment: best idea is probably to use some form of feature detection and come up with an alternate method of preseting that information for touchscreen devices

Answer (score 2):

simple and no javascript needed.
Here's the fix

add this to your css mediaquery

> body {cursor: pointer}

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var hidestuff = function() {
    // Hide lots of extra information with image, span, link elements
    // $(elm).hide();
}

$('html').touch(hidestuff).click(hidestuff);
```

CSS:

```
.hidestuff { position: absolute; z-index:1}
```

So, if user touch anywhere but the element in need to tap, the "hidestuff" will be hidden

Hope this helps :/